# UpdateProject Method

Tags: ms-project

I'm attempting to update a task using the "Mark on Track" via VBA. When I record with a task selected the following code results:

```
Sub Macro4()
    UpdateProject All:=False, UpdateDate:="8/14/18 4:00 PM", Action:=1
End Sub
```

In my code I have a variable tskCurrent that is defined as Task. How do I apply the UpdateProject method to the task variable tskCurrent?

Answer (score 0):

[UpdateProject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/project-vba/articles/application-updateproject-method-project) is a method of the Application object, not the Task object. So you need to select the task first:

```
Sub UpdateTask()
    ' ... declare and set tskCurrent as a Task object and StatusDate as a Date variable

    ' show all tasks before using Find method
    Application.FilterClear
    Application.SelectAll
    Application.OutlineShowAllTasks
    ' find tskCurrent and update it
    Application.Find Field:="UniqueID", Test:="equals", Value:=tskCurrent.UniqueID
    Application.UpdateProject All:=False, UpdateDate:=StatusDate, Action:=pj0to100Percent
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I’m looping through a lengthy list of tasks performing some calculations on each. For speed reasons, I was hoping there was a way that the task to update didn’t have to be selected. As I encounter each task, I indeed have a Task object defined as tskCurrent and date variable assigned to the project status date. I can speed things up by not performing the clear, select all and outline expand within the loop I suppose. Thanks again.